# Is there a way to find a specific permutation of an array?

Tags: java, permutation

If I have an array that looks like `{1,2,3,4}` and I want to find the 5th permutation is there a way to do this without calculating permutations 1-4.

I am trying to do this for an array of size 52 and I believe 52! is equal to something like more atoms in the universe so finding all permutations of that would be fairly processor intensive......and impossible...

**EDIT:**
I'm not sure if this is helpful or not but this is the code for the current `shuffle()` method I am using to shuffle a deck of cards, I would like to also use permutations...

```
// mean around 234.95 pokes to get a random shuffle in blackjack after 1,000 iterations of a sample of 10,000 shuffles

public void shuffle(int seed) 
{
    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    Card bottomCard = deck.get(deck.size() - 1);
    int i = 0;
    while(!deck.get(0).equals(bottomCard))
    {
        Card poke = deck.get(0);
        deck.remove(0);
        deck.add(rnd.nextInt(seed), poke);
        System.out.println(i++);
    }

    deck.remove(0);
    deck.add(rnd.nextInt(seed), bottomCard);
}
```

Comment: Are you entirely sure you mean permutation? Or perhaps you meant a combination, where the output should be `1, 2, 3, 4`, `1, 2, 4, 3`, `1, 3, 2, 4` i.e. rearrangement of elements without repetition.

Comment: Also, what format is your permutation supposed to follow? Please provide the first 5 'permutations' of the output for reference.

Comment: I don't have any format, if it helps its supposed to be a permutation of a standard deck of 52 cards. @RoboMop

Comment: Just google `rank and unrank permutation`